# Clock and dynamic layout

Tags: java, android, layout, timer

How can i show hour minutes and seconds of clock in Textview continuously as i am using dynamic linear layout`this format works on static layout but not on dynamic layout please help me thanks?

- List item

  ```
  public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {

  Button b;
  ScrollView scrollview;    
  int count = 4;`enter code here`
  private int mHour,mMinute,mSecond; 
  int min,hr,sec;
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_button);     
    Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        min = mMinute;
        hr = mHour;
        sec = mSecond;
        String timeSet = "";

        if (hr > 12) {
          hr -= 12;
          timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hr == 0) {
          hr += 12;
          timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hr == 12)
          timeSet = "PM";
          else
          timeSet = "AM";          
          String minutes = "";
          if (min < 10)
          minutes = "0" + min;
          else
          minutes=String.valueOf(min);                
          String secs = "";
          if (sec < 10)
          secs = "0" + sec;
          else
          secs = String.valueOf(sec);


          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

          }
       };

         mHandler.post(mUpdate);            
         scrollview = new ScrollView(this);
         LinearLayout linearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);
       linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);             
       scrollview.addView(linearlayout);          
       TextView t = new TextView(this); 

     t.setText(hr + ":" + minutes + ":" + secs+""+timeSet);           
    linearlayout.addView(t);       
    for(int i = 0; i<count;i++)
    {
     LinearLayout linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearlayout.addView(linear1);              
        b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(""+i);
        b.setId(i);
        b.setTextSize(10);
        b.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
        b.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
        b.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));            
        linear1.addView(b);                            
    }                
    this.setContentView(scrollview);
  ```

  }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have to call setText() on your TextView *inside* your Runnable run() method. The way it is now the text will only be set once when the Activity is created.

Comment: and where to addview that linerarlayout.addview(t) gives me error t cannot resolve a variable

Comment: You have to declare your TextView before you reference it, and most likely make it final, or declare it as a member variable on your Activity.